# px.choropleth not showing any map, but just the legend!

Tags: python, jupyter, plotly

I am unable to figure out why below code doesn't give proper o/p as maps, but just legends.

*Summary_Table is my data_frame that contains 'id' and 'Total Deaths' and geojson_data contains the location data.

```
fig=px.choropleth(Summary_Table,
             locations='id',
              geojson=geojson_data.to_json(),
              color="Total Deaths"
             )
fig.show()
```